# Подключение виджета ВК

Tags: javascript, api, post, вконтакте, виджет

подскажите пожалуйста, как можно сделать автоматическую смену постов через официальный виджет Вконтакте?

```
<div id="vk_post_1_45616"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function(d, s, id) { var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]; if (d.getElementById(id)) return; js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id; js.src = "https://vk.com/js/api/openapi.js?169"; fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs); }(document, 'script', 'vk_openapi_js'));
  (function() {
    window.VK && VK.Widgets && VK.Widgets.Post && VK.Widgets.Post("vk_post_1_45616", 1, 45616, 'ZMk4b98xpQZMJJRXVsL1ig', {width: 500}) || setTimeout(arguments.callee, 50);  }());
</script>
```

У меня получилось только сделать актуальный пост, а вот как автоматически менять один пост на другой я не понимаю...

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask); особенно на рекомендации по поводу заголовка обратите внимание.